# ooVoo SDK initialization issue

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, oovoo

I am having an issue in my project, when I am loading oovooLibrary in my app it is not responding for 5 seconds and then crashing without any error. Please help me in this.

My code is

```
        ooVooClient.setContext(app);
        ooVooClient.setLogger(this, LoggerListener.LogLevel.Debug);

        try {
// I am getting no responce for this line
            mConferenceCore = ooVooClient.sharedInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed that issue, I was calling `ooVooClient.setContext(app);` from `MainActivity` class so it was not accepting that context - app (`getApplicationContext()`), So I initlialized it in `MainApplication.java` and stored that in static variable and used that in other classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
  private ooVooClient sdk = null;
  private ApplicationSettings settings = null;   

 if (!ooVooClient.isDeviceSupported()) {
                    return;
                }

                settings = new ApplicationSettings(this);

                ooVooClient.setLogger(this, LogLevel.fromString(getSettings().get(ApplicationSettings.LogLevelKey)));
                ooVooClient.setContext(this);

                sdk = ooVooClient.sharedInstance();
```

Check this https://github.com/oovoodev/Android-SDK-Sample

Comment: I ran this project it is working fine but when i am implementing same in my own project it is crashing

Comment: can you post your crash log here?

Comment: it is not throwing any error it is just hanging my device, and than it gives "app not responding error"

Comment: Once you got "app not responding" error don't click OK on device. Check the android logcat(Android Montior) in android studio

Comment: I tried with debugging.. and with same steps you are saying.. but not getting any error in logcate

Comment: Did you followed all these steps

https://github.com/oovoodev/Documentation/blob/master/Android%20Documentation/Eclipse%20and%20Android%20Studio%20Integration%20Guide.md

If you followed all the steps but still is not working. Consume their android sample project and convert it as your project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114213/discussion-between-armv-and-dindinii).

Comment: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load ooVooSdk from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.jiffysoftwaresolutions.myapplication-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.jiffysoftwaresolutions.myapplication-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null

Comment: try to create the new project and follow the steps for integerate the sdk which they are provided in their docs or else consume their sample project

Comment: I think you have missed the .so files. You have to add .so files under app/src/main/jniLibs

Comment: create the folder under your project app/src/main/jniLibs and copy these two folders armeabi-v7a & x86 from oVoo android sample project(app/src/main/jniLibs)

I hope this can fix your issue.

Comment: I created new project and in this it is working fine

Comment: But in my project i am getting :
 W/dalvikvm: Exception thrown (Ljava/lang/NoClassDefFoundError;) while throwing internal exception (Ljava/lang/NoSuchMethodError;)
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000018 (code=1), thread 20853 (Thread-12992)